# TCP/IP Printing Issue in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, tcpip, usb, printing

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 Entrprise in a VM on my laptop. I am having problems setting up a printer. It's an HP PSC 1355 - drivers were installed automatically when I plugged the device into a USB port. I enabled the Print and Document Services Role (Print Server and Internet Printing) and can print to the printer no problem.

I also have a combined 4-port router/print server that has a single USB port. The printer can be accessed via a standard TCP/IP printer port - `http://192.168.1.1:<port number>/printers/My_Printer`.

When I try to add the printer via Devices and Printers, the wizard is unable to locate the printer on the network and prompts me for "Additional Port Information". I select "Network Print Server (1-port, USB)" and select the appropriate driver. The wizard then confirms that the printer has been added successfully, but if I print a test page, it does not print out.

After about 5 mins, the print job status in Print Management shows an error.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to share the printer on your laptop.  Than connect to the laptop with your VM over the network, install the printer and then print to it.

Comment: Will this work? When I'm using the VM (which is on the same laptop) I can't browse shared folders or printers as the computer name for the VM on the network is different.